# Anchor Links not scrolling on iPad

Tags: ipad, scroll, hyperlink, anchor

I'm creating a single page website on squarespace (Pacific template https://pacific-demo.squarespace.com) which has a navigation bar that appears on scroll with anchor links that scroll to their section.

Everything works fine on desktop and on mobile but on iPad the links jump to their section instead of scrolling.
(even the template has this problem, but I'd like to fix it).

I used this code which works on phones but not on ipad:

```
<script> 
 $(function() {
        $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
           if (screen.width <= 1129) {
          if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
              $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
              }, 1000);
              return false;
            }
          }
           }
        });
      }); 

</script>
```

Any suggestion on how to sort this out?

Thank you

Comment: add link or code?

Comment: @DubZ I've updated the question... I'm still working on the website so for now I can only provide a link to the template I am using. The navigation ber on my site works exactly the same way